# What rule has been used here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In this example how did we get the last step. I don't understand what is the rule used here.

$y=x^{-2}$

$ y+dy=(x+dx)^{-2}\\
       =x^{-2}(1+\frac{dx} {x})^{-2} $

Comment: Rule of Exponents (?): $(ab)^k=a^k b^k$.

Comment: Looks like it is just $(x + b)^k = (x + x\frac bx)^k = (x[1+ \frac bx])^k = x^k[1+bx]^k$.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you, that was very helpful.

Comment: @fleablood That last $bx$ should be $\frac bx$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factor as $$x+dx=x\left(1+\dfrac {dx}{x}\right)$$

then raise to the power $-2$,

$$(x+dx)^{-2}=x^{-2}\left(1+\dfrac {dx}{x}\right)^{-2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just factor out $x$ from the parenthetical expression. We begin with

$$y+dy = \frac{1}{(x+dx)^2}$$

Note that, by factoring out an $x$, we have the following:

$$x+dx = x \left( 1 + \frac{dx}{x} \right)$$

Since the denominator of the fraction is squared, then, we apply this twice. We thus see following:

$$y+dy = \frac{1}{(x+dx)^2} = \frac{1}{(x+dx)(x+dx)} = \frac{1}{x \left( 1 + \frac{dx}{x} \right) x \left( 1 + \frac{dx}{x} \right)} = \frac{1}{x^2 (1 + \frac{dx}{x})^2}$$

And of course since $a^{-1} = 1/a$ for $a \ne 0$, your result follows.

Comment: Thank you, that was also helpful, I cannot upvote yet.